# Powershell If statements write to txt file

Tags: powershell, csv

Ok, I have a script that creates a gui and then runs several "if statements" in order to output lines of text.  It will correctly write to the console, but cannot figure out how to get it to a csv file.
Note : Some of the code is not shown due to the length of the script.  Notes are included where appropriate.

```
function Build_GV
{
if ($GVC.checked -eq $true) #GVC is defined in the gui code
{
write-host "GV is present.  Version is $gv_ver" #$gv_ver is in the gui portion of the code
}
if($GPC.checked -eq $true) #GPC defined in gui code
{
write-host "GP is present.  Version is $gv_ver"
}
```

If the checkboxes are checked, the output on the console is:
GV is present. Version is 33.2
GP is present. Version is 33.2

I would like those two lines to be written into a csv file like this:
GV is present. Version is 33.2,
GP is present. Version is 33.2,

Comment: [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)

Comment: @stackprotector  I saw that page.  I tried this and it just puts the entire line in the file such as: write-host "GP is present.  Version is $gv_ver"  I just need the text in quotes with the variable replaced (which it does correctly to the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Added `$locations = $(` before the first "if" statement.  Changed `write-host` to `write-output` Then closed the parens at the very end. then before the end of the function, added `$locations | out-file -filepath "C:\Testpath\text.txt"`

Works like a champ now.